# Failed to instantiate module indexModule due to: Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/$injector/modulerr?p0=n...)

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use ngCookies in a project of mine, but I'm getting the error in the title whenever I try to inject it.

HTML:

```
    <script src ="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

//where I believe the issue is happening
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-cookie/4.0.9/angular-cookie.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



 <script src ="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular-route.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.13.4/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css">
```

Angular:

```
angular.module("indexModule", ["ngRoute", "ngCookies", "ui.bootstrap"]);
```

I tried using the CDN provided in the Angular documentation, but I get the same error.

Comment: Did you load script for `ui.bootstrap` ?

Comment: I agree with Rashad, most likely you are not loading ui.bootstrap.  That said, if you switch to the unminified version of angular temporarily, you will get a much richer error message.

Comment: I included the ui.bootstrap in my code. I just didn't include it in this because it wasn't the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is in `angular-cookie.min.js`. The link you provided is not valid. I have tried following without any error. see [demo](https://jsbin.com/vedorocoyu/edit?html,js,console,output)

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular-cookies.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

By your code angular is unable to inject `ngCookies` in `indexModule`. So it is needed to change the cdn of `angular-cookies.js`.

```
<script src ="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular-cookies.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src ="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular-route.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.13.4/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css">
```